# Slideshow Background on FFmpeg for Streaming

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg

I currently have a GIF looping in the background. But I want to add an image slideshow that features 10 images on loop. How can I achieve this?

My current code example that uses a GIF is below:

```
FFMPEG=ffmpeg
GIF= /home/randomgif.gif
STREAM_KEY=
TEXT=current_song.txt
COLOR="0xFFFFFF"
BCOLOR="0x000000"
INRES=1366x768 # input resolution
OUTRES=1366x768 # output resolution
FPS=15 # target FPS
GOP=30 # i-frame interval, should be double of FPS,
GOPMIN=15 # min i-frame interval, should be equal to fps,
THREADS=4 # max 6
CBR=1100k # constant bitrate (should be between 1000k - 3000k)
QUALITY=veryfast # one of the many FFMPEG preset
AUDIO_RATE=44100
KEYINT=$(expr $FPS \* 3)

$FFMPEG -thread_queue_size 1024 -f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:Loopback,1,0 -fflags +genpts -ignore_loop 0 -r $FPS -i $GIF \
-vf drawtext="fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/slant.ttf:bordercolor=$BCOLOR: borderw=1: fontcolor=$COLOR:textfile=$TEXT:reload=1:y=10:x=5:fontsize=38" \
-vcodec libx264 -x264opts keyint=$KEYINT:min-keyint=$KEYINT:scenecut=-1 -b:v $CBR -minrate $CBR -maxrate $CBR -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-s $OUTRES -preset $QUALITY -acodec aac -threads $THREADS -fflags nobuffer \
-bufsize $CBR -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/$STREAM_KEY" \

2> log_stream.txt
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: It streams to YouTube and plays the GIF in a loop. I want to move from using a GIF to a slideshow of images that loop.

Comment: What have you tried? Please do not only respond in the comments. Instead, [edit] the post with this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `-fflags +genpts -ignore_loop 0 -r $FPS -i $GIF` with `-framerate $FPS -loop 1 -i img%d.jpg` where the images are `image1.jpg`, `image2.jpg` ... `image10.jpg`. The images should be the same resolution.

Comment: I end up with:

[image2 @ 0x55c9a7520800] Could find no file with path 'img%d.jpg' and index in the range 0-4
img%d.jpg: No such file or directory

Comment: Sorry, for `img%d.jpg`, files should be `img1.jpg`, `img2.jpg` ...

Comment: Awesome, very close to what I need. The pictures are scrolling through at the moment is there a way to make the picture display for a certain period of time before moving to the next?

Comment: Set `framerate` value to reciprocal of frame duration i.e. for 5 seconds per frame, `1/5` Then add `fps=15` before the drawtext.